# How to make backdrop cover parent modal when another modal is opened

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a web application where the users can open modals to do all sort of things, and there will be many layers of modals to be opened, sometimes 4 or more.

The following css demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
.modal-backdrop { z-index: 1040; }
.modal { z-index: 1050; }

.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop { z-index: 1060; }
.modal .modal  { z-index: 1070; }

.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop { z-index: 1080; }
.modal .modal .modal { z-index: 1090; }
```

But I need it to be generic (and not a nasty hack like above), what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the bootstrap code.

**Bootstrap v3.3.7**, line 1108~1110.
Changed from

```
this.$backdrop = $(document.createElement('div'))
  .addClass('modal-backdrop ' + animate)
  .appendTo(this.$body)
```

to

```
this.$backdrop = $(document.createElement('div'))
  .addClass('modal-backdrop ' + animate)
  .appendTo(this.$element.parent())
```

this modification will make the backdrop appear on the parent element, instead of the end of the body, thus changing the z-index stacking context to allow a second backdrop to stay on top of the first modal.

**WARNING**: Be aware that changing the original bootstrap code can cause side-effects to your application, if you want to use this solution, proceed with caution.

This answer is open to edits with side-effect info.
*Side-effects*

- If your modal is inside a `position`-ed element, the backdrop may not cover the entire page
- Parent CSS rules may apply to the backdrop by accident, you may have to override those rules with your own `.modal-backdrop` class.